# codemirror-vim unbind terminal

Tags: next.js, key-bindings, codemirror

So I'm using codemirror-vim in my app and I want to unbind keymap that opens terminal by default is it : or (shift-;) so I'm trying unbind it with `Vim.unmap("Shift-:", "normal");` but it doesn't work

I tried unbinding with:

```
Vim.unmap("Shift-:", "normal");
Vim.unmap("Shift-;", "insert");
Vim.unmap("shift-:", "normal");
Vim.unmap("shift-;", "insert");
Vim.unmap(":", "normal");
Vim.unmap(";", "insert");
Vim.unmap("shift+:", "normal");
Vim.unmap("shift+;", "insert");
```

nothing works